# Ambiguous class occurence in Haskell

Tags: class, haskell, ambiguous

Using `Trees` and defining a new "`Eq`" I'm getting an `"Ambiguous class occurrence 'Eq' *** Could refer to: Hugs.Prelude.Eq Main.Eq".`

I'm aware that I'm trying to add a new definition for the existing Eq-Class of the prelude, but I don't want to use import prelude hiding (Eq), because my new equality is using the "==" for numerical types. The Operator is called "=+", because it is not a real equality (which I think is already 'loaded' via deriving), but only a structural one.

```
data Tree = Nil | Node Int Tree Tree deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
instance Eq Tree where
    Nil =+ Nil      =  true
    (Node a tl1 tr1) =+ (Node b tl2 tr2) = (a==b) && (tl1==tl2) && (tl1==tl2)
```

I'd be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you need this at all? Why can't you simply use the derived `Eq` instance, which is basically equivalent to your custom one anyway (except for the missing cases `Nil =+ Node ...` which will crash your program if you keep them undefined). `==` is not "pointer identity" like in Java, in case you think so.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a new class to coexist with a predefined one, you should obviously give it a properly distinguishable name, e.g.

```
class PseudoEq x where
  (=+) :: x -> x -> Bool

instance PseudoEq Tree where
    Nil            =+ Nil            =  true
    Node a tl1 tr1 =+ Node b tl2 tr2 
          = a==b && tl1==tl2 && tl1==tl2
```

Simply qualifying the instance with `Main.Eq` does pretty much the same thing, but it's confusing to call your class `Eq` at all if it's "not real equality".

(Though `==` also doesn't need to be a proper equality; for many types this only means "equivalent in all regards the user can observe".)

Comment: Okay, using your hints I found a solution which does a real comparison of the tree's structure: [Can't post the code in a readable way] wich includes `Nil =+ Nil   =  True`, `Nil =+ (Node a tl tr) = False`,`(Node a tl tr) =+ Nil = False`,`(Node a tl1 tr1) =+ (Node b tl2 tr2) = (tl1=+tl2) && (tr1=+tr2)`

I realized I made some mistakes within my first try. 
Nontheless my textbook says there should be a way of using an instance of Eq, meaning the solution of Zeta is asked for. I won't write it down ;o)

Comment: If the textbook says there should be an instance of `Eq` it either means the `derived` instance, or a custom one for `Prelude.Eq`; but almost certainly not a _new class_ also named `Eq`. "Overloading class names" is something only done in big projects that change the entire standard class hierarchies in some subtle way, like the [numeric prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude).

Comment: Hang on, actually even numeric-prelude doesn't do that... it uses its own, dramatically shortened names like `C` for a ring (roughly equivalent to `Num` numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Just use fully qualified class names:

```
module Main where

data Tree = Nil | Node Int Tree Tree deriving (Prelude.Eq, Ord, Show)

class Eq a where
  (=+) :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Main.Eq Tree where
    Nil =+ Nil      =  True
    (Node a tl1 tr1) =+ (Node b tl2 tr2) = (a==b) && (tl1==tl2) && (tl1==tl2)
```

#### But don't do that

You shouldn't create such ambiguity in first place. For example, your `Eq` should be called `StructEq` instead, if it's *"only a structural one"*.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deriving `Eq` if you want to write a custom one? Just drop `Eq` from the deriving clause, and this should all work.

Comment: Because I didn't want to implement a real equality, but a structural one. I posted a (for me) working code above.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't noticed that the derived instance was actually used... it looked like you were just deriving an instance and then trying to write another one.